# can not import views to urls in django 3.1.4

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

this is my directory

[image]

this is my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from mysite.mysite.views import hello

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/',hello()),
]
```

this is my views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello world')
```

but i got this error:

```
No module named 'mysite.mysite'
```

Comment: I think you got the contents of you views.py in your urls.py file and vice versa.

Comment: thanks so what can i do to fix it @redcricket

Comment: You probably just made a mistake writing up your post.  Your `urlpatterns` list should be in your urls.py not your views.py

Comment: i edit my question @redcricket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `views.py` is in same directory than you have to put like this in your `urls.py`

```
from mysite.views import hello
```

and inside your `urls.py`

```
path('hello/',hello,name="hello"),
```

if this will not work than write like this

```
from . import views
```

inside `urls.py`

```
path('hello/',views.hello,name="hello"),
```

Comment: i got the same error as before No module named 'views' @Ankit

Answer (score 0):

In the standard Django structur you would only edit urls.py an settings.py in mysite and place your helloworld stuff in a helloworldapp folder. Then register the helloworldapp in settings.py REGISTERED_APPS. There is dozens of tutorials showing just these steps. I am not sure if Django can find your stuff if you just place it in mysite like in a standard appfolder

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using two time mysite
I is possible to one Mysite is project and other one is the folder for whole project
Try to remove one mysite
Try this
From mysite.views import hello
Or
path('hello/',hello),
Next time please put the whole picture of the project